# Unable to decipher strange open circle symbol for a vector

Tags: matrices, optimization, vectors

I'm reading Optimization Algorithms and Applications by Arora and I came across the following way the author has depicted a vector. It's just a list of the $n$ variables in a general objective function. However, I cannot decipher the meaning of the open circle underneath the vector open bracket.

I'm not sure if it's just a quirky way to write a vector or if it means something important.

[image: The vector in question is here]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a printing or typesetting error to me, and nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: I'd guess it was just a typo.

Comment: Thanks, both of you are right. The problem is throughout the text with the circle replacing all manner of important mathematical symbols. Essentially unreadable. Will leave the question up for anyone else who stumbles upon this book.